# SQLAlchemy/Python: Use elements of a list as table names when transferring tables to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I have a list of table names. I want to query each of those tables by looping through the list and send them to a MySQL database such that the table names in the new database are same as those in the list. In the last line, **str(i)** corresponds to the table name. Apart from str(i), I've tried "%s"%i and "{}".format(i) but to no avail. Would be glad if someone could help me out. Thanks!

```
for i in listOfTableNames:
    i = pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM "+i+";", engine1)
    i.to_sql(str(i), engine2, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Wasn't a particularly bright question.

```
for i in listOfTableNames:
temp = str(i)
i = pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM "+i+";", engine1)
i.to_sql(temp, engine2, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```